# A problematic sport application to sign up on time

Tags: android, apk

The problem is that there is a sign up for every new sport lesson every weeks, but there is no notification when the course is available, and around 10 places.
Then I can't access to the lesson I want except if I spend my life on the phone.

So, is there a way or a script to watch this application every "n" seconds in order to send a notification on my smartphone when a new lesson is out ?

I have some ideas but no competences for this, webdesigner myself it's not my field of competences...

Maybe a script to sign up automatically ?
A way to question the application every 10 seconds for example and send a notification to my phone ?

Thanks and have a good day :)
(excuse for my bad english I'm not native)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.